# Translating letters not in 7bit ASCII to ASCII (like ń to n and ą to a)

Tags: python, string, utf-8, ascii

I'm looking for a fast and possibly convenient way in Python 3 to translate strings with non-ascii letters to words with only ascii letters.

Examples!

żółw => zolw

móżdżek => mozdzek

łódź => lodz

and so on...

There are many letters in national alphabets that can be turned into ASCII letters (like ń to n). I can do it manually for my language (Polish), by specifying how to translate each letter. But is there any automated way to do that? Or some library which would do what I need?

Pythons `str.encode()` won't do, because `"żółw".encode('ascii', 'replace') == "???w"` and `"żółw".encode('ascii', 'ignore') == "w"`...

I can do such translation for polish letters but I don't want to do it for every other language:

```
>>> utf8_letters = ['ą','ę','ć','ź','ż','ó','ł','ń','ś']
>>> ascii_letters = ['a','e','c','z','z','o','l','n','s']
>>> trans_dict = dict(zip(utf8_letters,ascii_letters))
>>> turtle = "żółw"
>>> out = []
>>> for l in turtle:
...   out.append(trans_dict[l] if l in trans_dict else l)
>>> result = ''.join(out)
>>> result
'zolw'
```

The above code does what I want with polish letters, but it's ugly :< What is the best way to do this?

Of course such translations will change the meanings of some words, but thats ok.

Comment: Keep in mind that in some languages, what some would consider an accented letter is considered a distinct letter in that language. For example, the letter 'å' in Swedish is typically considered a distinct letter from 'a', and not simply the letter 'a' with a ring above it.

Comment: I'm aware of that... The point is that when I write in polish somewhere, where my national letters aren't supported I use this "translations" I wrote about. I guess people from other countries have their own ways of writing in such environments. I'd like to know how such transformations can be done.

Comment: @John Saunders, thanks for making my answer completely invalid.

Comment: How did I make your answer invalid?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Well, the [python-3.x] tag does make a difference.

Comment: So, the question is specific to this particular version of python? If so, then put that tag back. But if it's not specific to a particular version, then the [tag:python] tag is better.

Comment: @Maciek I've updated my answer with an even better solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [**unicodedata**](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/unicodedata.html) module can be used for this.
It has functions to manipulate Unicode character names: [`name`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.name) and [`lookup`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.lookup).

Now let's look at them closer.

```
name('Ż') == 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z WITH DOT ABOVE'
name('ł') == 'LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH STROKE'
lookup('LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z') == 'Z'
lookup('LATIN SMALL LETTER L') == 'l'
```

See a pattern? Let's make a function that utilizes it:

```
import unicodedata

def normalize_char(c):
    try:
        cname = unicodedata.name(c)
        cname = cname[:cname.index(' WITH')]
        return unicodedata.lookup(cname)
    except (ValueError, KeyError):
        return c

normalize_char('ę') == 'e'
normalize_char('Ę') == 'E'
normalize_char('ś') == 's'
```

It looks for the word *WITH* in the character name, removes everything that goes after it and feeds it back to the [`lookup`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.lookup) function.
If there is no '*WITH*', `ValueError` is raised and when there is no character with such name, `KeyError` is raised, so the function returns the character unchanged.

And here is a function that "translates" a string based on the previous function:

```
def normalize(s):
    return ''.join(normalize_char(c) for c in s)

normalize('Móżdżek') == 'Mozdzek'
```

So this solution is obviously very good, but I'll leave the previous ones below.

---

The [`unicodedata`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/unicodedata.html) module also has a function that promises similar results – [`normalize`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) with `'NFKD'` parameter (compatibility decomposition), but it misses most characters.

---

If you have the character data, the code you provided can be improved.

```
letters={'ł':'l', 'ą':'a', 'ń':'n', 'ć':'c', 'ó':'o', 'ę':'e', 'ś':'s', 'ź':'z', 'ż':'z'}
trans=str.maketrans(letters)
result=text.translate(trans)
```

[**Here**](http://semplicewebsites.com/sites/default/files/latinise_compact.js_.txt) is a nice table with character data. This is JavaScript but can be used easily for Python.

---

And if you don't mind using external libraries, you might want to try [**Unidecode**](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/0.04.1). It was made just for this.

Comment: Unfortunatley unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', "żółw") == 'żółw' not 'zolw' :(

Comment: What about decomposing to NFD and then throwing away all the combining marks?

Comment: This table you liked to is great and this Unidecode library is quite promising! As for now I think there are no better ways to do that.

Comment: @DougMcClean: Won't work for characters which don't decompose (e.g, ¶).

Comment: Ahh, yeah, if you want to do stuff like that I think you need to build a table. Or do something crazy like rendering and then OCRing.